# How to display multiple dimensions on rows in MDX query?

Tags: ssas, mdx, rows, dimensions

I have measure called `Sales KG` in my cube and two dimensions: `Groups` and `Formats`.

Is there anyway to display last ones in single row?

I have this query:

```
select
[Measures].[Sales KG] on Columns,
[Formats].[Format_TT].[Format_TT] on Rows
from [Model]
```

and it's working, but when I try to follow examples from Internet and turn it into:

```
select
[Measures].[Sales KG] on Columns,
{ ([Formats].[Format_TT].[Format_TT]), ([Groups].[Group_Name].[Group_Name]) } on Rows
from [Model]
```

Everything ends with error saying that `Elements, tuples and sets in functions must use same hierarchy`.

I am new to MDX. I don't know why it works for others and no work for me.
3 days ago I didn't even knew about it's existence.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving you the above error because you are breaking dimensionality and hierarchility. When you write

```
 { ([Formats].[Format_TT].[Format_TT]),
 ([Groups].[Group_Name].[Group_Name]) }
```

MDX translates that you have a set (marked by {}), containing two tuples `([Formats].[Format_TT].[Format_TT]),([Groups].[Group_Name].[Group_Name])`, marked by "()" each. Now the issue is all the tuple in a SET must contain then same hierarchies(The principle of hierarchility), plus they should be in the same order (Dimensionality)

```
select
[Measures].[Sales KG] on Columns,
{ ([Formats].[Format_TT].[Format_TT], [Groups].[Group_Name].[Group_Name]) } on Rows
from [Model]
```

Comment: @Kosmos read the edit i made, this has the braket typo fixed and wlso explains the concept of sets and tuples.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it better now. Thanks.