# Set requirement on the axis

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

In MDX, I've read that the `SELECT` clause selects **sets** on up to N axes. What about the following queries then that still work?

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Count] -- no set specified here?
FROM
    [Mycube]
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Count],
    (Conference.Conference.members, Division.Division.members) -- a tuple?
FROM
    [Mycube]
```

Why are both of the above 'ok' then?

Comment: They should not work, which platform are you using? SSAS?

Comment: I've tried it in both SSMS and VS (bids I think?) Maybe the set brackets are optional when it's implied?

Comment: Does the below answer help? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will work since for column axis you just have a single member, here MDX will translate it to a set automatically. But If you add a dimension member to it then you will first have to enclose it with "()" to indicate that it is a tuple. OR If you add two Measures in the above query you will have to enclose them in "{}".

You may also want to read this.

[How to display multiple dimensions on rows in MDX query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692910/how-to-display-multiple-dimensions-on-rows-in-mdx-query/54693136#54693136)