# Why use a CROSSJOIN when it seems to be implied?

Tags: ssas, mdx

What is the difference between the following two, and which is preferred over the other?

```
CROSSJOIN(
    [Team].[Hierarchy].[Conference].[NFC],
    {[Team].[Name].[Name].[Detroit Lions], [Team].[Name].[Name].[Minnesota Vikings]}
    )
```

And:

```
(
    [Team].[Hierarchy].[Conference].[NFC],
    {[Team].[Name].[Name].[Detroit Lions], [Team].[Name].[Name].[Minnesota Vikings]}
    )
```

It seems any sets supplied within a tuple are automatically crossjoined, so why the need for the CROSSJOIN` keyword/function? Is it correct to say that the following three are the same?

```
CROSSJOIN({}, {}, ...) == ({}, {}, ...) == {} * {} * ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no diffrence between the above two statements. However in the last statement

> CROSSJOIN({}, {}, ...) == ({}, {}, ...) == {} * {} * ...

the last part "({}, {}, ...) == {} * {} *" is not necessarily true. When you write
"{} * {}" it only exist if both sets (represented by {}) are same in dimensonility and hierarchility.
For details refer
[Dimensionality and hierarchility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692910/how-to-display-multiple-dimensions-on-rows-in-mdx-query/54693136#54693136)